# How to persist a choice in a Xamarin Alert Dialog

Tags: xamarin, android-alertdialog

I do not believe this is duplicate question. I can preserve the choice coming back from the Dialog box; the problem is, it's always -1.

This dialog box displays correctly, except that the user's choice is not captured:

```
    var dialogView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_view, null); 
    Android.App.AlertDialog alertDialog;
    var items = new string[] { "A","B","C" };
    var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
    using (var dialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this))
    {
        dialog.SetTitle("Choose Letter");
        dialog.SetMessage("Just Click!");
        dialog.SetView(dialogView);

        dialog.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (s, a) => { });
        dialog.SetPositiveButton("OK", (s, a) => {
            {
                if (a.Which!=-1)
                //BUT I don't know how to persist the choice
                //when I click on one of the letters, it briefly
                //shows the choice (the background is briefly grayed
                //but the choice doesn't persist
                //so when I click OK, a.Which is -1
                {
                    //do things with the choice 
                }

            }});
                alertDialog = dialog.Create();
    }

        dialogView.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview).Adapter = adapter;
        alertDialog.Show();

}
```

And this is the axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I 1) show the user's choice more than the line being briefly grayed and 2) how do I persist that choice?

Comment: I reopened your original question.  This question, however, IS a duplicate of that one, so if you would please delete it

Comment: @Ron,please delete this thread, I have answer your issue in this thread.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59020513/how-to-persist-a-choice-in-a-xamarin-android-alert-dialog